# How to uncheck all the checkboxes in expandable listview?

Tags: android, checkbox, expandablelistview

I want to uncheck all the checkboxes in child of expandable listview but the problem is that it uncheck only visible checkboxes in a view group. The invisible checkboxes are not getting unchecked. Please help me.

```
public void uncheckAllChildrenCascade(ViewGroup vg) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
            ((CheckBox) v).setChecked(false);
        } else if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            uncheckAllChildrenCascade((ViewGroup) v);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the Checkboxes in an arrayList:

```
  final ArrayList<CheckBox> myCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
    final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (checkBox.isSelected()){
                myCheckBoxes.remove(checkBox);
            }else{
                myCheckBoxes.add(checkBox);
            }
        }
    });
```

And then set the Checked to false:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < myCheckBoxes.size(); i++) {
        myCheckBoxes.get(i).setSelected(false);
    }
```

Done you have all the CheckBoxes unchecked :)

Comment: Actually i have a Clear Button in the footer of expandable listview in main activity..when i click on the button this method uncheckAllChildrenCascade() is called and i pass expandable listview in it..

Comment: the method is in the Adapter class

Comment: Just on your adapter make a checkbox onClickListener, when you click the checkbox is added to arrayList. When you click the clean button take the checkboxes of the ArrayList and set checked to false.

Comment: i am using setOnCheckedChangeListener() and storing in arrayList but i am getting garbage value in the checkbox...

Comment: what do you mean "garbage value in the checkbox"?

Comment: when i Toast the checkbox value then it give me garbage value

Comment: Print here the garbage value please

Comment: android.widget.CheckBox{42293e68 VFED..C. ........ 33,2-73,45 #7f0a006f app:id/check_filter}

Comment: Yes thats good, is not garbage, is the "id" of the checkbox, i dont know why you want to take the value of the checkbox... but did you try to uncheck the checkboxes of the arraylist?

Comment: for(int i =0;i>myCheckBoxes.size();i++){
myCheckBoxes.get(i).setChecked(false);
}

Comment: if (isChecked) {
myCheckBoxes.add(childViewHolder.mCheckBox);

Comment: i have tried to uncheck the checkboxes in a method but not getting unchecked

Comment: Sry try with:
 checkBox.setSelected(false);

Comment: Actually the size of myCheckboxes arrayList is 0 when we try to use it in the method

Comment: change checkBox.isChecked() to checkBox.isSelected() on the if condition

Comment: arraylist still empty?

Comment: yes sir! :( Actually I found that when i call the method from another activity it doesnt change the value in arraylist but if i use a count(for my test) method inside the class it gives us the correct answer that values exits in arraylist

Answer (score 0):

You only uncheck visible checkboxes cause you use ViewHolder.
Don't you have a list or someting to store your data?
Change your list and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: i have Hash Map to store the checked checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

1. Maintain a ArrayList for parent checkbox.
2. Add a listener for parent checkbox inside getGroupView.
3. set the ArrayList value for the position true if it is checked, else set it false.
4. now call notifydatasetchanged inside this checkbox listener which is inside getGroupView.
5. inside getChildView, if ArrayList has true at current groupPosition, then check the child checkbox, else uncheck it.
   I hope this is what you needed.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
      if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_header,null);
    }
   CheckBox chkGroup = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkGroup);
   chkGroup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chkGroup);
           if (cb.isChecked()) {
              privateGroupChecked.set(groupPosition, true);
           else  {
              privateGroupChecked.set(groupPosition, false);
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
       });
     return convertView;
   }

   @Override
   public View getChildView(final int groupPosition,final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater)this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_child, null);
       }
       boolean isGroupChecked = privateGroupChecked.get(groupPosition);
       if (isGroupChecked) {
       chkDevice.setChecked(isGroupChecked);
        }
        else
        {
          chkDevice.setChecked(!isGroupChecked);
        }
        return convertView;
       }
   ```

Comment: whats is privateGroupChecked?

Answer (score 0):

```
private final Set<Pair<Long, Long>> mCheckedItems = new HashSet<Pair<Long, Long>>();
final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_checkbox);
    RelativeLayout relativelayout=(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl_selected);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    final Pair<Long, Long> tag = new Pair<Long, Long>(getGroupId(groupPosition), getChildId(groupPosition, childPosition));
    cb.setTag(tag);
        cb.setChecked(mCheckedItems.contains(tag));
relativelayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (cb.isChecked()) {
                cb.setChecked(false);
                mCheckedItems.remove(tag);
                Shop.iv_shopbyCategory.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Shop.tv_rl_selectedshopByCategory.setText(" ");
            }
            else
                {
                    mCheckedItems.clear();
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    mCheckedItems.add(tag);
                    final String SelectedGrouposition=(String) getGroup(groupPosition);
                    final String SelectedChildposition=(String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                   
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have a expandable listview in which when i click on relative layout it changes the checkbox checked or unchecked and when i select new  check it will remove all selected check..

for me its working and hope it will work for u also...

## Try this